# What is the name of this type of link encoding?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, encode

I have received an email. In the body there is a link with a strange type of encoding. The link is: `http://0301.0275.0x95EC`, but when I hover over the link, it shows down on the browser `http://193.189.149.236`.

I'd like to know what kind of encoding this is. Is it hexa or Unicode or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not encoded.

The target link is specified by an IP address (not by a domain name)

However instead being expressed as 4 decimal dot separated digits (the usual way) the address is specified as follows:

The first two digits are octal

```
0301 (base 8) = 192 (base 10)
0275 (base 8) = 189 (base 10)
```

The last part of the address is packed in a 2 bytes digits that decomposes in

```
95 (base 16) = 149 (base 10)
EC (base 16) = 236 (base 10)
```